# Does React remove the node with display:none from DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In our JavaScript code some of the nodes have `display:none` defined in their inline styles. We don't see any of those nodes in the DOM rendered by the browser. Is it a common thing in React or JavaScript ?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with React or JavaScript at all.

That's just CSS.

`display:none` means "don't display this element at all". This differs from `visibility:hidden` btw, as that just makes it invisible, but leaves its place in the page.

Comment: True. React does not automatically add inline-styles, unless you provide them yourself either.

Comment: Well , does it mean that it doesn't render it in DOM ? when I inspect it.

Comment: No. If you inspect DOM you'd be able to see the node with style attribute containing `display: none`

Comment: So the whole thing is that I don't see it in the DOM , and my question is if it's because of React or Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

They should be rendered by React but stay hidden because of the CSS rule.

If you don't want to render a component at all, you can use inline conditions. E.g. (using jsx):

```
render: function () {
    var isVisible = determineIfVisible();
    return (
        <MyComponentParent>
        {(isVisible)
        ?  <MyComponent />
        :  ''
        }
        </MyComponentParent>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` makes it not get rendered in a dom, but would stay in the virtual dom. The element is excluded when browser merges html dom with cssom to create render tree